# Hall Effect pulse multiplier circuit

Tags: 555, pll

I would like to use a Phase Locked Loop (PLL) to multiply a 4x signal to be an 8x signal, and modify the same 4x signal to be a 64x signal so that all three signals are available as a 5v clean low - high pulsed output.  This can be two identical circuits but for the multiplier using I was thinking of a 555 as a schmitt trigger maybe to feed the PLL.  The origin signal is 5v from a hall effect sensor

i have seen some PLL circuits but I am lost on how to make the multiplier amount itself

Comment: The trick to a PLL multiplier is a frequency divider.

Answer (score 2):

PLL frequency multipliers work by using a frequency divider.

You have a clock, lets say at 1MHz.  You would like to multiply it by 8 to get an 8MHz clock.

You do it like this:

1. You have a voltage controlled oscillator (VCO) that runs somewhere around 8MHz.
2. You use a divider (some flip-flops) to divide the VCO output by 8.
3. You use the PLL to compare the original 1MHz clock with the output of the frequency divider.
4. The PLL puts out a voltage proportional to the difference of the two clock signals.
5. The PLL output drives the oscillation frequency up or down until the original clock and the divider output are equal.
6. This is called "lock."  When locked, the VCO output frequency is exactly the clock frequency multiplied by the divider factor.  So, in our example, we start with 1MHz and divide the VCO output by 8 and end up with an 8MHz signal from the VCO.

---

The [datasheet for the ancient 4046](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scha002a/scha002a.pdf) gives an example of how all of this works.

The 4046 has a PLL and  VCO onboard.  You add your own dividers, and get a multiplied output signal.

Example circuit:

[image]

This multiplies a 1kHz signal by up to 999.  So, output frequency from 1kHz to 999kHz, in 1kHz steps.

Note that it is composed of three sections:

1. PLL
2. VCO
3. Frequency divider

If you have a PLL, then you have to implement a VCO and divider to get your multiplied clock.

---

Since your input signal comes from a hall effect sensor, a schmitt trigger to square up the edges is probably a good idea.  A 555 may not be needed.  There are ICs that are **only** schmitt triggers.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that there will be a range of input signals over which lock is possible? If the incoming pulses vary over a wide frequency range the PLL may not be able to lock in.